# automated test generation?

Tags: php, unit-testing, code-generation, phpunit

currently im writing a test for a report function
the more functionality the project gets the more
reports need to be written

in my case reports get a few 'search' paramters and limitations like
number of rows or such

now my question:
anyone knows how to generate test cases automatically for a function
which has a well known set of possible parameters using phpunit?

i read about some tools like quickcheck for other languages
but does automated test generation exist for php?
or anyone has a suggestion how to automatically create tests?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the list of well-known parameters somewhere (in a dedicated file or in the unit-test source file, write a [parameterized test-case](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html) and iterate over the parameters.

Comment: Here is an example about [how to write a parameterized test case using PHPUnit](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-testing/practical-php-testing-patterns-46).

Answer (score 5):

PHPUnit has a [test case class skeleton generator](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/skeleton-generator.html#skeleton-generator.test). Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

To generate basic PHPUnit files from your classes, you can use the PHPUnit skeleton generator.

Download it from :

- Github : https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator
- Composer : `"phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator": "*"`
- DDL : `wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-skelgen.phar`

Documentation is above : https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/skeleton-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by Ionut, skeleton generator is what you're looking for. [Here's a nice tutorial](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/628-Improved-Skeleton-Generator-in-PHPUnit-3.html)...

Netbeans does it all with one click, [if you're that way inclined](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html).